# Browsing a db file

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I create a button on click of that button a perticular location will open and I have to select the db file from that location. 
Like we use to do in the data dictionary if we want to connect to the database we used to click on the browse button after that we select the db file from the location and the database will connect. I need to create a utiliy like data dictionary's connect db option. Is there any command for it?

Comment: Where is your list of "locations" coming from?  Are you asking about OS level "db files" such as "sports2000.db" or internal db "files" (also known as tables) such as "customer"?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the DataDictionary?

Otherwise:
1. First you need to connect to the DB. Check the `CONNECT` method.
2. To look at tables and fields in the database you can used "Virtual System Tables".

Just a short snippet to get you started:

```
FOR EACH _file NO-LOCK:

    IF _file._file-name BEGINS "_" THEN NEXT.

    DISPLAY _file._file-name.

    FOR EACH _field OF _file NO-LOCK :

        DISPLAY _field._field-name.

    END.

END.
```